# Bootstrap Calendar - events_source

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am using Bootstrap Calendar - https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar

And I am running into an issue. In the documentation, they have a file - events.json.php, which is a JSON file which will be pulled into the calendar.

My issue is that this is not pulling through, and I know the events.json.php file is working fine!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
      <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
      <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_js/calendar.js"></script>

<div class="current-calendar-date"></div>
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calendar = $("#calendar").calendar(
    {
      tmpl_path: "/tmpls/",
      events_source:"/events.json.php",
    });      
  });
</script>
```

There are no console errors or anything, but no information as to why the file will not appear?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT

Even hardcoding an event doesnt work??

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar({
tmpl_path: "/tmpls/",
  events_source: function(){

    return  [
       {
           "id": 293,
           "title": "Event 1",
           "url": "http://example.com",
           "class": "event-important",
           "start": 1441843200, // Milliseconds
           "end": 1443225600 // Milliseconds
       },

   ];

}});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed, it was the timestamp, to make it milliseconds, it needed an extra '000'